# How to have an event occur after x seconds?

Tags: c#, monogame, timer

I want a method to run after every 10 or 15 seconds.

My timer is set to:

```
timer = (double) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

What would be the logic to check for every 10 or 15 seconds?

Answer (score 4):

There's no magic way to do this in MonoGame that I know of. The basic idea is fairly simple though; create a variable to keep track of the delay and when it gets to zero fire your method.

The simplest way to do this is to introduce a member variable in your Game class to keep track of the remaining delay and have it fire your method when the delay reaches zero, then reset the delay each time.

```
    private const float _delay = 15; // seconds
    private float _remainingDelay = _delay;

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        var timer = (float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        _remainingDelay -= timer;

        if(_remainingDelay <= 0)
        {
           MyMethod();
            _remainingDelay = _delay;
        }

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

A slightly more fancy approach is to create a class to encapsulate the logic. I have one in my engine called a DelayedAction.

```
public class DelayedAction
{
    public DelayedAction(Action action, float delay)
    {
        TimeRemaining = delay;
        Action = action;
        Delay = delay;
    }

    public Action Action { get; private set; }
    public float Delay { get; private set; }
    public float TimeRemaining { get; private set; }

    public bool Update(float deltaTime)
    {
        TimeRemaining -= deltaTime;

        if (TimeRemaining <= 0)
        {
            Action();
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

The idea here is very similar, except that you can create more than one instance of it and run them in a loop. One difference with this implementation though is that it returns false after the action has fired rather than repeating the action over and over. I'm sure you could make the modifications to make it repeat if so desired.